# How to access ant variables in python script

Tags: python, build, ant, python-2.4

I have made build.properties file in ant in which I have defined some variables as shown below

```
webinf.dir = WEB-INF

src.dir = ${webinf.dir}/src
```

Now these variable are accessed in ant build.xml file and its working fine. But I want to access these variables in my python file also.
And I want value of **src.dir** to come as `WEB-INF/src` not as `${webinf.dir}/src`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a single properties file (e.g. build.py) that's read by Ant and Python. For example:

**build.xml**

```
<project default="build">
    <property file="build.py"/>
    <target name="build">
        <echo message="${src.webinf}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

**script.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("build.py")
print config.get("properties", "src.webinf")
```

**build.py**

```
[properties]
src.webinf = WEB-INF
```

**Example usage**

```
$ ant
Buildfile: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clicks/test/build.xml

build:
     [echo] WEB-INF

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

$ python script.py 
WEB-INF
```

Comment: Actually on second thought, using a shared properties files limits the key-value pairs you can have as properties, so you may want to investigate some third party Python libraries that can read Java properties files

Comment: Hi but my problem is src.dir = ${webinf.dir}/src   I can't define variable as defined above. and while retrieving value of src.dir I want it to come full path.

Comment: I edited the Python script to use a ConfigParser. Does that work for you?

Comment: Ya I tried it but its not usefull as I am not getting the full path of src.dir   It returns ${webinf.dir}/src  but I want output as WEB-INF/src

Comment: The problem is that src.dir is created by Ant at runtime. Python cannot access that variable since it only has access to the initial properties file. Can't you just refactor your variables to put as much as possible into the properties file so that it can be shared with the Python script?